# the bar d3 using v3 does not rotate but the axes can rotate perfectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([height,0], .1)

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([0, width],.1);
```

{......}

```
state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", y.rangeBand())
  .attr("height", function(d) { return x(d.x1)-x(d.x0); })
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

I don't know why my bar rotated 180 degree, I want the y-axes show the bar. So it will look like vertical bar.
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Swap width and height. Besides that, you have to set the rectangles's `x` and `y` attributes.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it! the bars went vertical but now all the bars pile up.

Comment: I added .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.state); })  and  .attr("x",  function(d) { return x(d.x1)

Comment: We need to see your data if you want proper help.